# Xor encryptor new line issue

Tags: c, fgets, fread

I have created a simple program that gets an existing file as input (**text content**) encrypts its content and the outputs the encrypted content to a file with filename specified by the user (`argv[2]`). The problem is that whenever `fgets` tries to read a new line character it terminates. So i would like to use `fread` instead to solve this issue but then another problem came over. it doesn't stops at the ned of the string (`\0`). So how can implement `fread` to terminate at the end of the string? the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Xor_key 0xCF

void xorInput(char *in, char *o) {
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *fp2;
  fp = fopen(in, "rb");
  if (fp==NULL) {
    printf("file isn't here...\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  char buf[1000];
  fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
  printf("file contents: %s\n", buf);
  int i;
  for (i=0; buf[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    buf[i] ^= Xor_key;
  }
  printf("Encrypted input: %s\n", buf);
  fclose(fp);
  fp2 = fopen(o,"w");
  fprintf(fp2, "%s", buf);
  fclose(fp2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [file_name]  [file_output_name]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  xorInput(argv[1], argv[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

- If this post is considered duplicate or violates any other site rule leave a comment and i ll delete it. Thank you for your time
- If you need any further informations let me now.

Comment: Is the content of the encrypted files text or binary?  If the encrypted file is binary, then finding the end of a _string_ appears to be contradictory.

Comment: Since you'll run the same program on both 'encrypted' and 'unencrypted' files, you need to ensure you read each byte in turn and (un)encrypt it before writing it out.  You could simply use `getc()` and `putc()`, or you could work in bulk with `fread()` and `fwrite()`.  Just make sure you keep a record of how many bytes were read, process those bytes, and write the processed version out.

Comment: @chux its text content.

Comment: Also, if you're on Windows, you need to open the files in binary mode (on Unix, there's no difference between text and binary mode). Note that the encrypted data is not text, in general (and unencrypting data requires binary input).  Good job on including the usage message (many don't; thank you for doing so).  However, the usage message isn't accurate; your program will be unhappy if either or both argument is left off the command line (so it should be `"Usage: %s file_name file_output_name\n"` without the square brackets.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i am currently using a linux OS but for the sake of compatibility i used `rb`. ths for the usage message notice

Comment: …and you need `"wb"` too for safety on Windows.

Comment: Take the time to understand charater encodings and bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adopting most of the suggestions from the comments, I created a file `xr71.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Xor_key 0xCF

static
void xorInput(char *in_name, char *out_name)
{
    FILE *fp1 = fopen(in_name, "rb");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to opn file %s for reading\n", in_name);
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp2 = fopen(out_name, "wb");
    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file %s for writing\n", out_name);
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[1024];
    size_t nbytes;
    while ((nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp1)) > 0)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; ++i)
            buffer[i] ^= Xor_key;
        if (fwrite(buffer, 1, nbytes, fp2) != nbytes)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to write %zu bytes to %s\n", nbytes, out_name);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp1);    // Error check omitted
    fclose(fp2);    // Error check omitted
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file_name file_output_name\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    xorInput(argv[1], argv[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that all error messages are written to standard error.  The `static` is there because of the compilation options I use (see below).  Public functions must be declared before being defined; all functions must be declared or defined before being used — with the sole exception of `main()`.

Compilation and test:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition xr71.c -o xr71  
$ ./xr71 xr71 xr71.v1
$ ./xr71 xr71.v1 xr71.v2
$ cmp xr71 xr71.v2
$ cmp xr71.v1 xr71.v2
xr71.v1 xr71.v2 differ: char 1, line 1
$ cmp -l xr71.v1 xr71.v2
   1   0 317
   2  65 372
   3  42 355
…
9034 252 145
9035 275 162
9036 317   0
$ ./xr71
Usage: xr71 file_name file_output_name
$ ./xr71 in
Usage: ./xr71 file_name file_output_name
$ ./xr71 in out err
Usage: ./xr71 file_name file_output_name
$
```

This is what should be expected.  The output file `xr71.v1` is different from the input file (that's good; it wouldn't be encrypted otherwise).  The output file `xr71.v2` is the same as the original input file (`xr71`), which is good; encryption plus decryption gives you back what you started with.

Answer (score 3):

The only encryption/decryption being done is to exclusive-or each byte with the key.

No need for buffers (other than it may help performance).  No need to look for the end-of-line nor the null character. Simply read 1 byte, `^` it, then then write.  Repeat unitl all the data has been read.

```
void xorInput(const char *in, const char *o) {
  FILE *fp = fopen(in, "rb");
  if (fp==NULL) {
    printf("file '%s' isn't here...\n", in);
    exit(1);
  }
  // Open in binary
  FILE *fp2 = fopen(o,"wb");
  if (fp2==NULL) {
    fclose(in);
    printf("file '%s' isn't here...\n", o);
    exit(1);
  }

  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    ch ^= Xor_key;
    fputc(ch, fp2);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp2);
}
```

Comment: I checked your code and it works fine. Thank you for your help